# xcode and avr arduino "Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2" error.

Tags: xcode, arduino, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

I am completely new to avr programming, and I am trying to get xcode to work with my Arduino Mega2560. I managed to get it working with embedxcode, but now I am trying a more slimmed down approach with the xavr project scheme. For some reason I cannot upload my code to the arduino. It gives me this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

The last bit of output I get is this:

```
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9801
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed

avrdude done.  Thank you.

make: *** [program] Error 255
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

I have uploaded the full output here: http://pastebin.com/y7Z5F5NP

I really hope somebody can help me figure out how to get this working - it would be a big help getting me started with my arduino :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify your makefile? If you did, you might put an extra space on the recipe line of the rule. The first character on the recipe should be a tab.